# NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification seems to get lost

Tags: xcode, icloud, notificationcenter

Trying to integrate iCloud, and trying to understand NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification. I have an observer setup to listen for it and everything works as expected, except when internet connection is lost. When it is re-acquired, the observer doesn't pick up any changes that occurred during that downtime. Any subsequent changes at this point get picked up (and also looks like the ones during the downtime get pushed through at this time as well) but I guess my confusion arises since the same observer can notify me of changes when the app first opens, regardless of what changes happened or if the internet was available or not. I would assume the observer would act the same in any case, but I am not seeing that behavior?